# Linear algebra: diagonalisation of antisymmetrisation

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm facing an apparent contradiction when trying to solve a linear algebra exercise. I am asked to find a basis for the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices such that the function
$$f(A) = A - A^t $$

is represented by the matrix

$$\left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right) $$

which would mean that some matrices are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ for $f$, which seems to be impossible.

Comment: I agree with your concern - providing you are only allowed to use a single basis for the space of matrices, this is impossible, as there are no eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$. However, you could replace the $1$ by a $2$, or redefine $f(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)$, and then you're fine.

Comment: Many thanks for clearing that out, I wasn't sure but indeed a factor $\frac12$ in the definition would save the exercise.

Comment: In that case I will make it a proper answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redefine $f$ as

$$f(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t).$$

This is the map that is usually called anti-symmetrization, and solving the exercise should tell you why!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$f(A)=A-A^t\implies f^2(A)=f(A)-f(A)^t=A-A^t-A^t+A=2A+2(f(A)-A)$$
hence we get

$$f(A)^2=2f(A)$$
hence the polynomial $x(x-2)$ with simple roots annihilates $f$ and then $f$ is diagonalizable.

Moreover, $A$ is an eigenvector associated to $0$ iff $A=A^t$ iff $A\in S_2(\Bbb R)$ which has the dimension $\frac{2\times 3}{2}=3$ and $A$ is an eigenvector associated to $2$ iff $A=-A^t$ iff $A\in AS_2(\Bbb R)$ which has the dimension $1$ so the matrix of $f$ relative to a basis of

$$\mathcal M_2(\Bbb R)=S_2(\Bbb R)\oplus AS_2(\Bbb R)$$
is
$$\operatorname{diag}(0,0,0,2)$$